# using simple html dom to find facebook username - php

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm using php and the simple html dom

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

I'm trying to extract the facebook, twitter, google, youtube and pinterest usernames from the addthis code below..

```
<!-- AddThis Follow BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" style="margin-top:-3px;">  
<a tabindex="2" class="addthis_button_facebook_follow" style="padding:3px 6px;" addthis:userid="namehere"></a>
<a tabindex="3" class="addthis_button_twitter_follow" style="padding:3px 6px;"  addthis:userid="namehere"></a>
<a tabindex="4" class="addthis_button_google_follow" style="padding:3px 6px;"  addthis:userid="namehere"></a>
<a tabindex="5" class="addthis_button_youtube_follow" style="padding:3px 6px;"  addthis:userid="namehere"></a>
<a tabindex="6" class="addthis_button_pinterest_follow" style="padding:3px 6px;"  addthis:userid="namehere"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-51e6691575bd9b10"></script>
<!-- AddThis Follow END -->
```

How can I get the usernames using the simple html dom?

I tried running this...

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.domain.com/');
foreach($html->find('a[class=addthis_button_facebook_follow]') as $element)
echo $element->class;
```

which outputs the class name:

```
addthis_button_facebook_follow
```

but how do I return the addthis:userid value?

```
addthis:userid
```

Comment: Try this: `$name = 'addthis:userid'; echo $element->$name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're not calling the attribute right. Consider this example:

```
// target the first link, since you only need one, and target the proper attribute
$id = $html->find('a[class="addthis_button_facebook_follow"]', 0)->{'addthis:userid'}; // first link facebook
echo $id; // namehere
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo $element->{'addthis:userid'};
```